# Removing numbers from a large range of numbers

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, range

I've got the following problem that I'm trying to find a more optimal solution for.

Let's say you have a range of numbers between 0 and 9:

```
Values: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
Index:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Now, let's say you "remove" 1, 4, 5, and 7:

```
Values: 0, -, 2, 3, -, -, 6, -, 8, 9
Index:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Where there is no value, all subsequent values are shifted to the left:

```
Values: 0, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9
Index:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

The value at index 1 has now become 2 (was 1), the value at index 2 is now 3 (was 2), the value at index 3 is now 6 (was 3), etc.

Here's the problem. I need to manage this on a larger scale, up to tens of thousands of values. A random number of those values will be removed from the original contiguous range, and potentially added back afterwards (but not in the same order they were removed). The starting state will always be a complete sequence of numbers between 0 and MAX_VAL.

Things I've tried:

1) Maintaining an array of values, removing values from that array, and shifting everything over by one. This fails because you're iterating through all the values after the one you've just removed, and it's too slow as a result. Getting the value for a given index afterwards is really fast though.

2) Maintaining a linked list of values, and removing the value by pulling it out of the list. This seems to be slow both adding/removing values and getting the value at a given index, since I need to walk through the list first.

3) Keeping track of the "removed" values, rather then maintaining a giant array/list/etc of values from 0 to MAX_VAL. If the removed values are stored in an ordered array, then it becomes trivial to calculate how many values have been removed before and after a given index, and just return an offset index instead. This kinda works, except it's slow to maintain the ordered array of removed values and iterate through that instead, especially if the number of removed values approaches MAX_VAL.

Is there some sort of algorithm or technique that can handle this kind of problem more quickly and efficiently?

Comment: IMHO i think the 3rd option is the best. Instead of keeping another array you could use bitmaps. Use the largest unsigned number your system has and use the bits as markers for present or not.

Comment: Can't you store those values in a string and copy in another one every numbers excepting for the one you want to remove ?

Comment: Instead of manually shift each number above the one you removed in the array, you could [move all of them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) at once. At least it will be a *little* more efficient than you doing it one number at a time.

Comment: The question becomes "which data structure provides the most efficient traversal along with efficient insertions and removals?" Not an easy question, as it is highly data dependent. In your case a red-black tree would provide lightning fast access to any element for removal, but insertions and the removal itself would be costly. So in optimizing, the question you have to answer is where are most of the operations occurring? Traversal? Insertions/Removals? Then you can narrow down your choice of data structures. (for simple integers, it is hard to beat an array for speed)

Comment: It's about a 30/30/40% split (adding, removing, and getting values for indices). On average, I'm dealing with anywhere from 7.5K values up to 80K.

Comment: 1) rangetree 2) skiplist 3) judy-tree

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some sort of algorithm or technique that can handle this kind of problem more quickly and efficiently?

The answer very much depends on typical use cases:

- Is the set of numbers typically sparse or dense?
- How often do you do insertions vs. removals vs. lookups?
- In which patterns are numbers inserted or removed (random, continuous, from the end or start)?
- What are there any memory constraints?

Here are some ideas for a generic solution:

- Create a structure that stores ranges instead of numbers.
- Start with a single entry: 0 - MAX_VAL.
- A range can have subranges. This resulting graph of ranges forms a tree.
- Removing a number splits a leaf range into two, creating two new leafs.

This algorithm would perform quite well when the set is dense (because there are few ranges). It would still perform somewhat fast when the graph grows (O(log n) for lookups) when you keep the tree balanced.

Comment: A good idea but how would this work using indexes? Is having the number of elements stored in each subtree enough? (So you don't have to iterate down the tree to 'manually' count.)

Comment: It's a contiguous set of numbers from 0 to MAX_VAL. It can easily be represented by a range, since it includes every number in-between. Likewise, the range is static, once the code is initialized that never changes. Insertions/removals/lookups are about a 30/30/40% split. Numbers are removed and inserted mostly at random. There are no memory constraints.

Comment: @Jongware Keeping a count of elements in each subtree sounds like a good idea to solve the index problem. Calculating the index of a number then is moderately fast: O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Now, let's say you "remove" 1, 4, 5, and 7:

```
Values: 0, -100, 2, 3, -100, -100, 6, -100, 8, 9// use a unique value that doesn't used in array
Index:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: The values are unsigned integers, but even if they were signed, that would still require me to iterate over all the values before a given index, and any contiguous values after the given index if that index specifies a removed value. This would be prohibitively expensive if I was trying to retrieve values near the end of the range.